# Djnago JS Reverse - I can't manage to load reverse.js on my page

Tags: javascript, django

I have a django up and I am trying to use this potentially very use-full app called "[django-js-reverse](https://github.com/ierror/django-js-reverse/tree/7cab78c4531780ab4b32033d5104ccd5be1a246a)" to reverse Django Urls on separate javascript files.

I installed the app,

`pip install django-js-reverse`

I added it to my settings.py,

`INSTALLED_APPS = [ ... 'django_js_reverse', ... ]`

I collected static ...but still I can't manage to load it.

`./manage.py collectstatic_js_reverse`

I added this line to load the script in my template

`<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'action/js/project_dashboard.js' %}"></script>`

However, when I load my page and check the developer console, I can see that the import of the .js failed.
[image]

The frustrating thing is that I manage to import other .js files that I made so the overall collectstatic process is working.  Ideas?
[image]